# Is it safe to drive a Motorhome on the Swiss Alps during Winter?

Tags: switzerland, road-trips, alps, motor-homes

We are planning a motor-home trip to Switzerland where the plan is basically to do sightseeing and staying away from crowd cities.

I would like to ask if it's safe/doable in general to drive motorhomes (more than 7 meters long) in the mountains during winter? Assuming the driver hasn't any experience in driving on the snow/motorhomes, but has already driven on the mountains before.

I know the question seems very naive, but I think it is also extensible to the quality of the roads in Switzerland during winter for this kind of driving. Since I don't know many people who drive motor homes, I am worrying that a plan like this is completely crazy and should not be pursued, so I would apprecite input from others, whether this is reasonable or not.

Comment: You don't say whether you have *any* experience of either winter or mountain driving, and move from "in general" to "assuming the driver isn't an expert in motorhomes" so the cautious answer IMO has to be **no**, it is unsafe without background experience in all three individually.

Comment: I edited the question to make it clearer.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. If you lose control on an icy surface in the mountains in a 7m motor home with no experience of ice or skid control, or a vehicle that size and weight, there is a high chance it will end badly. It is not the place to learn winter driving and I would not attempt it without prior experience, and being familiar with the vehicle and its characteristics.

Comment: 'In the Alps' is also a very vague description of what kind of roads you are planning to drive on. There are roads in the Swiss Alps, which are just as good as any other road in Switzerland and there are probably just as in the neighbouring countries, roads where motorhomes are not even allowed to drive, not even in the summer.

Comment: To me, it depends on how you are flexible. When it is snowing, it may be better not to drive. But after 4 hours (or one day or maybe two) you can drive. But plan. some road may be difficult to drive if you do not know well how to drive a motorhome (think about narrow roads, with a public bus on other direction, and a cliff and snow).

Comment: I think, with the combination of COVID 19 and you not being experienced in driving a motorhome on mountain roads in winter, you will be better off staying in France and out of the mountains.